# update active directory from Ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++

How to update Active directory from Ax 2012 ?

for example, how to update a username / phone no of the user in the Active directory from Ax 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [.NET Interop features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc598160.aspx) of X++ to call in managed code, then follow the examples here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Basically, I would write my own C# library that contains logic to update the Active Directory and then just invoke methods in this libraries from X++.